# Timestamp comparison in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, timestamp-with-timezone, sql-timestamp

I have below query in spark sql

```
sparkSession.sql(f"( SELECT * FROM {ordersTable} \
                    WHERE lastUpdated >= current_timestamp() - INTERVAL 24 hours)")
```

The date-time  in lastUpdated is stored in UTC format eg 2023-09-14T22:47:42.187Z. I know that the current_timestamp() gives the local date-time on the server where the code is running but will the current_timestamp be automatically converted to UTC format for the purpose of comparison here?

Comment: Should be easy enough to test...

Comment: My guess is it should not convert automatically. Maybe try like this ...
WHERE to_utc_timestamp(lastUpdate, current_timezone())